# Is there a way to run some script before the upload starts in php?

Tags: php, nginx

Can you run some script before the uploading of a file starts in php?  Example, I'm POSTing to upload.php, and in that file I want to check their $_SESSION first before I start wasting bandwidth on them and the file stats uploading to my server.  I'm using php 5.2.11 on nginx.

```
<?php
  if ($_SESSION['admin'] == 'YES') {
    // do upload here
  } else {
    exit;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The request doesn't get to the PHP engine until after the file has been uploaded.

Comment: The fundamental reason for this is that the upload is just big chunk of encoded data in the body section of the request. In PHP level, you cannot prevent a client making POST request to arbitrary location with data in the body. In server level it's technically possible (close the connection if no valid session id found in headers), but I think no web server can be configured at this level unless you write a custom module etc. In nginx you can set _client_max_body_size_ limit, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the upload is part of the request and is done before PHP even comes into play.

There *may* be a way around this using the technique of those PHP-/Perl-based uploaders that somehow hook into the uploading process, but then, there also may not. Especially when you're using a different web server.

I would do a quick Ajax-based check for the right session, and bind that to the `submit` event of the form you are uploading the file with. It may take half a second, but is completely unobtrusive for the user.

Comment: @COl. Shrapnel I assume he wants to make sure the session hasn't expired.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an ajax call on the page the form is submitted to check their session state before allowing the form to submit.

Comment: that's not an answer. Ajax cannot be used as it's just the same as regular form and can be easily avoided

Comment: +1 - it's the nearest thing to a valid solution for the question asked, although you'd be a bit daft to use an asynchronous call from the onsubmit method.

Comment: I can think. That's much better

Comment: To avoid unnecessary argument:

You cannot, using only php, check a session variable *before* a file is uploaded. The only possible way to do what the OP is asking is to bind an ajax request to the onSubmit.

90% of users are not going to modify the form to get around the ajax call. If they do, their session is checking in upload.php. Just saying.